# Parse - Geopoint with lat/lng set to 0 preventing location based query

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, geolocation, geopoints

I have some `Schools` within my database with the `Geolocation` value set to `{latitude: 0, longitude: 0}`.

I want to query schools based on my user's location, which is `t.GeoPoint {_latitude: 48.87513, _longitude: 2.3389439999999695}`.

This is how I query them :
      var school_query = new Parse.Query("School");

```
  school_query.near("Geolocation", this.geopoint);
  school_query.limit(10);
  school_query.find().then(...)
```

The 10 `Schools` return have their `Geolocation` field set to `{latitude: 0, longitude: 0}`. Obviously, this is not what I want.

I tried all I could to exclude those `Schools` from the results, such as creating a {0:0} geopoint, and using `notEqualTo` it. I tried to limit the results to 10km around my user.

Nothing works, 0 valued schools are still returned first. 
Is there anyway to circumvent this without having to play with the data?

Any suggestion is most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the geolocation is null then those objects will be ignored when there is a location based query constraint. My guess would be that `this.geopoint` doesn't have the lat/long pair values of `{_latitude: 48.87513, _longitude: 2.3389439999999695}` and isn't being initialized or accessed correctly.